# Material UI strange blue line when overflow attribute is added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

I'm using **Material-UI** with my React application. I'm also using styled components and I'm viewing the app in a Chrome browser. The issue I'm having doesn't occur when using a Firefox browser.

When applying the overflow attribute in my styled component, I'm seeing this blue line towards the bottom of the modal. This only appears when I'm playing with the size of my browser window. As I gradually bring my browser window closer to normal size, the line goes away. I'm not sure why this is or what I can do to fix it.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
export const ScrollableModal = styled(MUIModal)(() => ({
  overflow: 'scroll',
}));

const Modal = ({ title, children, actionsLeft, actionsRight, ...rest }) => {
  const wrappedTitle =
    typeof title === 'string' ? <Typography>{title}</Typography> : title;

  return (
    <ScrollableModal {...rest}>
      <Container>
```

I've left the rest out because it's not relevant to my question.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm describing:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

I guess that's the `outline` property what they mentioned in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/#simple-modal) for simple modal:

> Notice that you can disable the outline (often blue or gold) with the `outline: 0` CSS property.

First needs to be added to the current style:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  modal: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '35vw',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 0.8,
    outline: 0, // add / remove
  }
});
```

Then it can be applied on the `Container` just like the following in the render:

```
const styles = useStyles();

return <>
  <Modal open={true}>
    <Container className={styles.modal}>
      <p>Simple Modal</p>
    </Container>
  </Modal>
</>
```

Result by adding and removing `outline` property with value `0`:

[image: modals]

I guess with styled components just create a styled `Container` with `opacity: 0` if you don't want to use `makeStlyes` for this purpose.

That resolved the issue for me.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @norbitrial.  I took your suggestion and implemented it into my styled component.  However, the blue outline still shows in chrome browsers.  I've tried setting `outline: 'none'` and `outline: 0`. No success

Comment: I've also tried `'& focus': {
    outline: 'none !important',
  },` . Still not getting rid of it

Comment: Did you try to apply only on the `Modal` or on the `Container`? Can you try also with `makeStyles` or adding `outline: 0` from pure CSS as well? I think these are worth a try if you haven't tried yet. Let me know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: Sure thing and thanks for the help.  I applied it to the container.  Unfortunately, with the project we're working on, we can only use styled components so makeStyles isn't an option :( .  I'll take a look when I get back to the app.  I'm thinking it has more to do with focus, aria and accessibility with certain browsers.

Comment: Thanks - I made the mistake of applying the styling on the modal rather than its child container